# HTML-Validator Errors and Warnings

Tags: validation, error-handling, warnings

I seem to have a lot of errors on my site, 397 Errors, 317 warning(s), according to http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.poker006.com/ . I was just wondering if knows an east way to tackle these errors and which ones are must fix ones?

Thanks,

Dave